# How to read Mac floppy on a PC?

Tags: mac, floppy

I have a floppy made on a Mac years ago.  I'd like to pull some files from it, but Macs haven't had floppies in forever, so I don't have one.  I tried an app called MacOpener, but it didn't seem to work, plus it was pretty old.  I even tried sharing the PC's A:\ drive and accessing it remotely from a Mac, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/) to read Mac media on PC.

Answer (score 2):

The PC floppy controller is generally [not flexible enough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_disk#Compatibility) to be able to read disks from other computers - a fact which sometimes frustrates the emulation community :)